# Zk how to override zkmax.wgt.Dropupload

Tags: javascript, zk

I need to override a method of the Dropupload widget.
This is my code in zk.xml

```
    <device-config>

<!-- Custom javascript snippets -->
<embed>
    <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">

        zkmax.wgt.Dropupload.prototype._dropAction = function(evnt){
        //my code
        }

    </script>]]>
</embed>

</device-config>
```

When i try to execute my application, javascript crashes and says that zkmax.wgt is undefined. I have zkmax.jar in my classpath and the Dropupload widget works perfectly (widhout my code).
I also tryed to debug javascript and zkmax.wgt is undefined (Same in IE10 and Fierfox).
How can i change Dropupload._dropAction method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

why not using lang-addon?
In your zk.xml put your add-on uri:

```
<language-config>
    <addon-uri>/WEB-INF/mydropupload-lang-addon.xml</addon-uri>
</language-config>
```

create the file **mydropupload-lang-addon.xml** and inside put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<language-addon>
    <language-name>xul/html</language-name>
    <javascript src="/mydropupload.js" charset="UTF-8"/>   
</language-addon>
```

create the file mydropupload.js and inside

```
zk.afterLoad("zkmax.wgt",function(){      
    zkmax.wgt.Dropupload.prototype._dropAction= function (){
        //your code
    }                   
});
```

Comment: The afetrLoad callback is called correctly. But _dropAction method of the Dropupload widget is still the same. I think I need to extend the widget and create a custom component.